# Getting the latest of column A and latest of column B for each group in SQL

Tags: sql-server, query

Say I have the following table:

```
id    type    time
1     a       2021-08-29 12:53:51
1     b       2021-08-22 12:53:51
1     b       2021-08-27 12:53:51
2     b       2021-08-24 12:53:51
2     a       2021-08-25 12:53:51
2     a       2021-08-21 12:53:51
```

How can I create a table that shows the earliest occurrence of `a` and the earliest occurrence of `b` for each `id` with a SQL query?

The output headers would be `id, first_a, first_b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output headers would be id, first_a, first_b.

This could be achieved using conditional aggregation and row_number function.

Try,

```
select id,
       max(case when type='a' then time end) as first_a,
       max(case when type='b' then time end) as first_b
from ( SELECT id,
              type,
              time,
              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id,type ORDER BY time ASC) AS row_num
       FROM test
     ) x 
where row_num=1
group by  id ;
```

Using `PARTITION BY id,type` we create an unique identifier number for each distinct id,type group starting from 1 (the first one).

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/M7l1WZtf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT for that.

```
SELECT pvt.id,
       pvt.a AS first_a,
       pvt.b AS first_b
FROM   (
          SELECT id,
                 type,
                 time
          FROM   NotProvidedName
       ) p
PIVOT (
         MIN([time])
         FOR [type] IN ([a], [b])
      ) AS pvt;
```